# commit one server dir contents to other directory using svnkit

Tags: svn, commit, svnkit

I want to commit one server directory contents (all versioned contents of versioned dir already present on server dir) to a new dir on same server using SVNKit (version 1.7).

This new dir can be already present; or have to add/make it at appropriate location based on abs path.
(adding new dir to server i can do)

but i am not able to commit source path contents to dest path (already present or newly created).

i understand since I want Server to server commit , Here, there will not be any working copy.

I checked solution mentioned in [Committing changed file via SVNKit without local checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711561/committing-changed-file-via-svnkit-without-local-checkout) 
but couldnt make it work as I am not getting what should source path and what should be dest path.

As a work around, I tried copy functionality, but as u know, with copy, earlier history of files will be retained... I was looking for creating a fresh version of all contents at source path to dest path.

Another thing i tried is making a temp local working copy at c:// drive, checking out code from source to this local dir and then committing it to dest path. but this is not approprriate way :( also, i can not delete the local temp working coopy; it says it contains root so cant be deleted.

Can anybody help me in server to server commit using SVNKit ?

Thanks.
-Aditya

Answer (score 0):

That's not that difficult. If you wanted to retain copy history, you could run the following code

```
ISVNCommitEditor editor = svnRepository.getCommitEditor("", null);

editor.openRoot(latestRevision);
editor.openDir("path", latestRevision); //or use addDir if it doesn't exist
editor.openDir("path/to", latestRevision); //or use addDir if it doesn't exist
editor.openDir("path/to/new", latestRevision); //or use addDir if it doesn't exist
editor.addDir("path/to/new/directory", "/path/to/old/directory", copySourceRevision); 
editor.closeDir();
editor.closeDir();
editor.closeDir();
editor.closeDir();
editor.closeDir();
editor.closeEdit();
```

But if you don't want to retain the history, you can create editor with

```
ISVNCommitEditor editor = svnRepository.getCommitEditor("", null);
```

and then call

```
anotherSvnRepository.setLocation(copySourceUrl, true);
anotherSvnRepository.update(copySourceRevision, "", SVNDepth.INFINITY, false, reporter, customEditor);
```

Instead of `reporter` use this code:

```
    ISVNReporterBaton reporter = new ISVNReporterBaton() {
        @Override
        public void report(ISVNReporter reporter) throws SVNException {
            reporter.setPath("", null, copySourceRevision, SVNDepth.INFINITY, true);
            reporter.finishReport();
        }
    };
```

`customEditor` should be a wrapper for `editor` constructed above, that would call `editor` with correct paths (maybe you should add some openDir/closeDir calls to make editor calls correct).

As an example, you can have a look at the sources of my [svnkitfilter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/svnkitfilter/) project that does similar things.

To understand if the directory/file exists or not use SVNRepository#checkPath method.